# loop in a loop not working

Tags: ios, swift, loops

I'm working on an app for school project.

After accessing the user's contacts, I want to loop through and show only the contacts who are also users of the app. *Their username is their mobile number.

below are 3 functions.

the first one **getAppUsers()** works fine.

the third one **getDisplayedUser()** does not work. and i wonder why

the second one **getUserContacts()** works. but it is only there to check which part of my loop isn't working. :/

so apparently my loop in a loop has something wrong which i can't figure out (it didn't even get to the "you're HERE"). please help me out. THANKS!

```
var appUsers = [String]()
var contactStore = CNContactStore()
var userContacts = [CNContact]()
var displayedContacts = [name: phoneNumber]()


func getAppUsers() {
    let appUsersQuery = PFUser.query()
    appUsersQuery?.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("WTF")
        } else if let users = objects {
            for object in users {
                print("FYEAH!")
                if let user = object as? PFUser {
                    self.appUsers.append(user.username!)
                    print(user.username)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func getUserContacts() {
    for b in userContacts {
        let c = (b.phoneNumbers[0].value).stringValue
        let d = c.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\D", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: c.startIndex..<c.endIndex)
        print("you got here")
        print(d)
    }
}

func getDisplayedUser() {
    for a in appUsers {
        for b in userContacts {
            let c = (b.phoneNumbers[0].value).stringValue
            let d = c.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\D", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: c.startIndex..<c.endIndex)
            print("you're HERE")
            print(d)
            if a == d {
                print("FOUND IT")
                print(b.givenName + " " + b.familyName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get an error or it is just working but you can't get the messages? If you don't get "you re here" print message thats probably because of userContacts or appUsers is coming with null value. Did you check these two arrays?

Comment: @firats you're right. getAppUsers() is printing(user.username) but it is not appending to my appUsers array. In fact, appUsers is coming to nil. this is puzzling. do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getDisplayedUser` should be call after the loop finished in in `getAppUsers` because it is executing in asynchronous mode. I added the row after finished loop below

```
func getAppUsers() {
    let appUsersQuery = PFUser.query()
    appUsersQuery?.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("WTF")
        } else if let users = objects {
            for object in users {
                print("FYEAH!")
                if let user = object as? PFUser {
                    self.appUsers.append(user.username!)
                    print(user.username)
                }
            }

            // Call it here please ..
            self.getDisplayedUser()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right! it worked like a charm! Do you have any further readings on asynchronous? this error got me pulling my hair for hours. I need to prevent it from happening again!

Comment: great. just take note anything using completion is asynchronous. can refer here for basic tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1

Comment: Also, i realised that my code is not be very efficient. it actually loops through again and all over again just to find current users within the users' contacts. anyway to go about it?

Comment: like that: 8885555512
5555648583
90998289
5555228243
5554787672
98152820
5556106679
5557664823
8885555512
5555648583
90998289
5555228243
5554787672
98152820
FOUND IT
5556106679
5557664823
8885555512
5555648583
90998289
FOUND IT
5555228243
5554787672
98152820
5556106679
5557664823
8885555512
5555648583
90998289
5555228243
5554787672
98152820
5556106679
5557664823
8885555512
5555648583
90998289
5555228243
5554787672
98152820
5556106679
5557664823